# How to pass the HTML attributes to a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, software-design

I am working with HTML forms and want to validate the content of the form and take some actions accordingly using javascript.
So, I am using one function which validates the content of the fields, below is the javascript function:

```
function validation(){
        let x = document.forms['registrationform']['firstname'].value;
        console.log(x);
        if(x.length > 15){
            let y = document.getElementById('firstname').style.borderColor = "#F33C15";
            return false;
         }
      }
```

I want to modify this function in such a way that instead of using the hard-values like "firstname", the values from the respective HTML tags can be passed to the js function.

For ex:

```
function validation(z){
        let x = document.forms['registrationform'][z].value;
        console.log(x);
        if(x.length > 15){
            let y = document.getElementById(z).style.borderColor = "#F33C15";
            return false;
         }
       }
```

INFO: the *"firstname"* is the id of a HTML tag in the DOM.

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Comment: What happens when you call `validation('firstname')`?

Comment: Show some html code and how you're calling the `validation` function

Comment: What's wrong with your own solution that you're showing as an example?

Comment: @DeC i am calling the validation() function from html as:
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" onfocusout="validation();" required maxlength="20" title="firstname" placeholder="First name" class="nrow" style="position:relative; border-radius:8px; background-color:#F0F0F0;">

Comment: @RifatBinReza the problem is that I am not able to pass the value of an HTML tag to javascript function.

Comment: @NicolasI I am calling the function as: onfocusout the js function is called.

Comment: Try this: `<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" onfocusout="validation('firstName');" required maxlength="20" title="firstname" placeholder="First name" class="nrow" style="position:relative; border-radius:8px; background-color:#F0F0F0;">`

Answer (score 1):

I prepared a sample here using this instead of just the element id.

```
    <input onfocusout="validation(this)">
function validation(z){
        let x = z.value;
        console.log(x);
        if(x.length > 15){
            let y = z.style.borderColor = "#F33C15";
            return false;
         }
       }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ckr6svhq/